# разблокировать ожидание дейтаграммного сокета

Tags: c#, udp

здравствуйте, подскажите как грамотно завершить такой код:

```
 Thread thrd = new Thread(()=> {
 UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(...);
 /*...*/
 while(true) {
     byte[] bytes = udpClient.Receive(...);
     /*...*/
 }
 });
 thrd.Start();
```

есть гуи, для того, чтобы оно не зависало, создается поток(вышеприведенный), в котором прослушивается соединение. если нужно закрыть, то жмакаем кнопку "закрыть" и, соответственно, закрывается только гуи, а этот поток так и продолжает висеть вследствие блокировки из-за метода  Receive... если закрывать UdpClient методом Close(), то вылетает исключение; thrd.Abort() тоже не помогает. как грамотно завершать поток с висящим Receive()?

Comment: а сделать проверку на наличие гуи условием цикла?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для досрочной отмены операций, в том числе выполняемых асинхронно, существует структура [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx), которую можно получить из экземпляра класса [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx). Вот как это работает:

Код, который запускает Task для получения асинхронного ответа от сервера (хорошей практикой является использование именно Task, а не Thread):

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Run(()=> GetResponse(cts.Token)); //асинхронно запускаем GetResponse, передав ему токен отмены; параметр этого метода должен принимать  CancellationToken (см. ниже)
```

Далее, собственно метод GetResponse, куда вы поместите код с udpClient.Receive:

```
void GetResponse(CancellationToken token)
{
     while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
     //цикл будет выполняться до тех пор, пока это свойство возвращает false;
     //оно вернет true (цикл завершится), когда кто-нибудь (в нашем случае обработчик нажатия кнопки) не потребует отмены операции
     {/* получить данные от сервера */}
}
```

Теперь кнопка, по нажатию которой вы хотите прервать основную операцию:

```
private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  cts.Cancel(); //запрос на отмену, теперь token.IsCancellationRequested = true
}
```

Единственная (несложная) задача - подумайте, как вы передадите обработчику нажатия кнопки объект CancellationTokenSource cts. Можно его сделать "глобальным" например.

Кстати, при создании CancellationTokenSource можно передать ему в конструктор объект типа TimeSpan, чтобы автоматически потребовать отмену через определенный промежуток времени.

Comment: спасибо, вот только не могу понять почему это помогло: cancellationtoken как-то разблокировал ожидание сокета? просто ладно бы был метод без блокирования, но в моей случае управление вошло внутрь while(!token,IsCancellationRequested) и зависло на строке с Receive...как мы вышли из цикла то этого?

Comment: @xperious, полагаю, все дело в том, что вы использовали конструкцию Thread первоначально. Такие потоки создаются как активные, приложение не может завершиться до тех пор, пока все активные потоки не прекращают свою работу (а метод Receive блокирующий). Task же использует потоки из пула, которые являются фоновыми, приложение их принудительно закрывает, когда активных не осталось. Вообще лично я предпочитаю пользоваться не блокирующими методами для чтения из сетевого потока, которые бы возвращали мне индикатор того, что больше нечего считывать (null, 0, -1), а не блокировали бы меня.

Comment: а это самописные методы то?

Comment: Необязательно. StreamReader.ReadLine вернет null если ничего в потоке нет. Тогда можно использовать такой код: 'string temp; while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)  {while ((temp = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null){ /* записать temp куда-нибудь */}}'. Здесь даже если поток пуст, то, пока токен не отменен, цикл действительно будет выполняться, а не блокироваться. Но если уж вы пользуетесь UdpClient попробуйте совместить токены со свойством UdpClient.Available>0 (выполняйте Receive только если >0)

Comment: В любом случае, при использовании Task, приложение ваше при прекращении своей работы будет гробить и ее, даже без токенов. Иной вопрос, что не всегда вам нужно завершать задачу исключительно после завершения работы приложения. Да и иногда нужно нам узнать каков статус задачи: TaskStatus.Canceled, TaskStatus.Faulted и т.д., о Canceled нельзя узнать без токенов (Task.Run( (cts.Token)=> {}, cts.Token) Здесь мы передаем токен еще и методу Run, чтобы в случае отмены его, Task имела статус Canceled. Для этого в основном делегате нужно не просто выйти, а вызвать token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

Comment: во, спасибо за разъяснение